# Groovy script to Add node in SAP CPI

Tags: groovy, sap-cpi

I was trying to add node using Groovy script but output is showing like input.

Input:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <Records>
     <Line>
     <Field1>ABC</Field1>
     <Field2>123</Field2>
     <Field3>XXX</Field3>
     <Field4>567890</Field4>
     </Line>
   </Records>
```

Code:

```
import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
import java.util.HashMap;``
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil;
import groovy.util.*;

def Message processData(Message message) {
//Body 
   def body = message.getBody(java.lang.String) as String;
   def root = new XmlParser().parseText(body);
   root.Line[0].appendNode("Field5", [:], "MyNewField");
   return message;
}
```

Please help in creating new node using Groovy script.

Getting this error when XML path also:

> No signature of method: groovy.util.NodeList.appendNode()

Answer (score 0):

You can create a node like this so `Field5` Node is added to each row inside data:

```
import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
import java.util.HashMap;
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil;
import groovy.util.*;

def Message processData(Message message) {
    def body = message.getBody(java.lang.String);
    def root = new XmlParser().parseText(body)
    root.data.row.each { row ->
        row.appendNode("Field5", "newfield")
    }
    message.setBody(XmlUtil.serialize(root));
    return message;
}
```

See [the groovyide.com/cpi code](https://groovyide.com/cpi/share/v1/zVRNb9swDP0rnk7O0Mr5aLeudV2s6YpcOmxLM-Tgi2YzjgZZ8iQ5aRb4v4-yZaTNet8MGKLeexRpkfSecFnVllzuyQ-V78gliW-eShFsQBuu5HVKRnSYkgBkpnIuCwQWj_enFym5SVIZf_8lvtagd9_AWHxrYRFNbazBVEoamFtma5PMF9Ppp_k8jo7wF9o7sIyLDkRY8JLbZDQcDuOosz2hVisDNkHYWx43_DckkzhqV49ZZZlwYGe08aLXAsY5s6z30mrrTdzccxD5KPl4O40jb7_kxsloPPHc-IibJMvl0nOTI-4sOX_3_uLD0NNnffToEP5ZJgE-_0su__RW4siXKo5e7T5yQtbAcuxf19RK5LN2h509AyHUG9KckEqrCrTl4DQNAibTvGqnANscUMvLSmkbZKqkhlW0YBa2bEd5RTOlgWa1sarMYUNrywV9AGNYAVep9H4_2YZ11IyZ9QOrDlShldrsKA4ZXZZigZq_uNbxLcKpzGEV-NMDzDpD8w4_P-yxslsHwT6VrkWc3g1ycN1TtAB7i0jY5iSYLOjcahzlwdXBBeNadJGwDTCpL0wb0OGAVs54hCcbujMHnd5pqasBxZJQYNk62CO4DU6TTtCJtpRVFcj8M15omJK2mucpOQlSgmFWbpsSf2TTLX3Gxmfs7wf3mjOBYx262IM-cQ221rL3QrBpq7-qZWbx34VVfHZjpGn-AA).

Given the xml you provided on the link:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VqlQueryRestResult>
    <responseStatus>SUCCESS</responseStatus>
    <responseDetails>
        <limit>1000</limit>
        <offset>0</offset>
        <size>3</size>
        <total>3</total>
    </responseDetails>
    <data>
        <row>
            <Field1>ABC</Field1>
            <Field2>123</Field2>
            <Field3>XXX</Field3>
            <Field4>567890</Field4>
        </row>
        <row>
            <Field1>ABC</Field1>
            <Field2>123</Field2>
            <Field3>XXX</Field3>
            <Field4>567890</Field4>
        </row>
        <row>
            <Field1>ABC</Field1>
            <Field2>123</Field2>
            <Field3>XXX</Field3>
            <Field4>567890</Field4>
        </row>
    </data>
</VqlQueryRestResult>
```

Comment: From OP: "Hi, really thank you so much for your response. My actual requirement contains multiple repeating nodes structure as in this case, I was getting similar issue." Long Groovy IDE URL in 2 comments, part 1: https://groovyide.com/cpi/share/v1/zVRtT9swEP4rnj-1U3H6AhsrIWiUoX4Y01gpqkT44CXX1pNjZ7ZT6FD_-86JK0rh-2Ypyvl57nzne_ETFaqsHB0-0Z86X9Mhjc8eC0lWYKzQ6jSlPdZNKQGV6VyoBQLTm8uD45SeJamKb3_L6wrM-gdYh18lHaKpiw3YUisLE8ddZZPJdDT6MpnE0R7-QvcCHBeyARGWohAu6XW73Thq5EDo-dyCSxAOUsCt-APJII7qf8Ccdlx6sBFqf9FbDuOcO761MvohiLi5FCDzXvL5fBRHQX7J9ZNefxC4_h43SGazWeAGe9xhcvTh4_GnbqAPt96jZ_c7kRBc_0ss_zQrcRRKFUd...

Comment: Part 2 of URL: ...vdh_t0CXwHPvXN7WW-bjeYWePQUr9jm46tDS6BOMEeJ0NAjYzoqynANscUFcUpTaOZLpglpdswR088DUTJcu0AZZV1ukihxWrnJDsCqzlCzhJVbD7xVe8ocbcLq94-UwtjNarNcMhY7NCTlHnFVcbvkc4VTnMSTidYNQZihd4_dYWK5p_mzw1un6IyekWZgtw54i06ngkVws2cQbHuH3SqKM_h-oKHggG850bC6bVZqUXbuDRtfx57VR5PfY63Qx4tvSuSVi3118b5iB5A2S-cq9s_PLEN8z8rtkuzrD6d917xssSVO6RVkrrBjlKaYfcDe87JKV4jbnHUurv13TV5vlAFLd5sSEvoQK4N4JLfDha_qZtb27AVUZtM4nAhpC6u-aVyhy-jdglOxWhm81f

Comment: Hi @SandraRossi. I don't understand your comment. Can you clarify for me? Do you need something?

Comment: Nope, sorry for disturbing. This was a comment that the Original Poster posted 2 years ago (Jul 25, 2021), targeted to you but added inside the question instead of comment. Yesterday, I edited the question to clarify it, and moved out this part into a comment.